# SPARQL Service on the Web

Tags: sparql, rdf, fuseki

If I have the IRI of an RDF dataset, is there any service on the web which can takes the IRI of the dataset and a SPARQL query and returns me sparql result ?

If I serve Apache Fuseki on my server, can I do this whereby it can take any IRI as the default dataset and perform queries on it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few such services - there is a reason they aren't common.

Loading a dataset of any size is expensive compared to the query.  Loading it for a single query is only practical if the dataset is small (say, a few thousand triples at most).

If there isn't a SPARQL endpoint for the dataset you should consider setting up your own server with the data already loaded.

If you need a "load-and-query" service, Apache Jena Fuseki1 provides this facility at `/sparql.html` (the form) and `/sparql` (endpoint).  Fuseki2 does not provide this feature, there is no configuration support.

Comment: Yes, it works I have just tried it, I have one problem with it, when the return content type for a request on a dataset url returns text/plain, i am getting this error """Expected BNode or IRI: Got: [DIRECTIVE:prefix]"""

Comment: Set the "Accept" field.  Looks like it is returning Turtle (the default for no conneg) but parsing as N-triples.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/) (my employer) hosts a couple of services that might be relevant.

Both of these offer Faceted Browsing over their data (at `/fct`), as well as the typical SPARQL interface (at `/sparql`), and various other [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/)-powered services.

The [LOD Cloud Cache](http://lod.openlinksw.com/) has been loaded with DBpedia and most every other data set from the [LOD Cloud diagram](http://lod-cloud.net/) which makes a suitable dump available.

[URI Burner](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/) imports data from submitted URIs, with RDFizing as needed via the built-in [Virtuoso Sponger](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtSponger).

If you want/need immediate and/or large RDF imports, and/or want to make demanding queries over the data that's been loaded, you may need to set up a relationship with us — as the default restrictions may block your desired activity. That said, just identifying yourself by logging in with any of several supported authenticating services (Twitter, LinkedIn, OpenID, WebID, etc.) lets you do a lot — and it may be enough for you.